# Firefox Add-on SDK 1.6.1 is it possible to make an uninstall button?

Tags: firefox, button, uninstallation, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a Firefox Add-on.  My boss wants a license agreement to pop up (Got that, it's working), the user can Accept or Decline.  I want the Decline button to uninstall the Add-on.  Can an Add-on SDK 1.6.1 Add-on uninstall itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asked and answered! thanks for posting the solution back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
let AddonManager = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm").AddonManager;
...
uninstallExtension(require("self").id);
...
function uninstallExtension(id) {
    AddonManager.getAddonByID(id,function(addon){addon.uninstall();});
}
```